# Caching problem with Firefox CSS set via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, firefox, browser-cache

I use a WordPress plugin to add via shortcodes one, two or three 'fontsampler' objects per specific page that each incorporate a text box and a font select box per fontsampler object.  The JavaScript hides all select boxes via CSS except the last one.

In Chrome and Edge there is never any problem but in Firefox mostly all the select boxes show and sometimes just the last (F5 always shows all select boxes, ctrl F5 gives variable results).
The webserver also uses Litespeed cache and goes via Cloudfare CDN but I can't see this is relevant since only a Firefox issue.

NB I also tried the code and just the plugin on a vanilla wordpress test server (so no server caching) and didn't see the issue so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here is the code if this helps:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  $("body").on("fontsampler.event.afterinit",".fontsampler-wrapper" , function () {
    // ‘this’ is div.fontsampler-wrapper.initialized  NB all 3x fontsamplers are initialised on first event but not drawn on page e.g. fontpickers (event fires up to three times)
    //first count the number of fontsamplers on the page
    var fsCount = $($(document).find(".fontsampler-interface")).length;
    //check to see if last fontsampler has fully initialised (painted elements on page) else end event and wait for next
    var fsStub=".fontsampler-id-";
     var fsLast=fsStub+fsCount;
     
         if ($($(document).find(fsLast)[0]).find(".fontsampler-ui-block.column.fontsampler-ui-block-fontpicker")[0] !== undefined) {
   
        var fontsampler2Exists = $(document).find(".fontsampler-id-2").val();
        var fontsampler3Exists = $(document).find(".fontsampler-id-3").val(); 
  
  if (fontsampler3Exists !== undefined) {
    
    //Three lines
//    $(fs).find(".fontsampler-ui-block.column.fontsampler-ui-block-fontpicker")[0].style.display='none';
    $($(document).find(fsStub+1)[0]).find(".fontsampler-ui-block.column.fontsampler-ui-block-fontpicker")[0].style.display='none';
    $($(document).find(fsStub+2)[0]).find(".fontsampler-ui-block.column.fontsampler-ui-block-fontpicker")[0].style.display='none'; 
    }
  else if (fontsampler2Exists !== undefined) {
    // Two lines
    $($(document).find(fsStub+1)[0]).find(".fontsampler-ui-block.column.fontsampler-ui-block-fontpicker")[0].style.display='none';  
  
  }
  else {
    // One line so don't hide any font picker
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm now wondering if the .style isn't always quite ready in the rendering in Firefox and I need to add a delay or try/catch?

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I have Firefox developer console open it always renders ok on just an F5 which reinforces the idea of a timing issue